# Scroll down, move up div?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to achive a effect that is similar to the one that can be found here http://www.geoffroydeboismenu.com/ , where the menu reveals itself by scrolling down, overflowing, in this case, the "picture" div.

I've this code atm;

```
$(window).scroll(function(){            
    $("#container").stop().animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow"); 
});
```

But it kind of does the exact opposite, where my div follows the scroll, instead of going up.

I want my #container div to overflow my #slider div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/Cc6sD/2/

I used native javascript as often as I could to stay as smooth as possible (but you can replace some parts of the code with jQuery methods, to ensure total cross browser compatibility).

***Edit:***
I edited the code (it worked only on chrome). It works now in all browsers except in Internet Explorer before version 9. If you want to support older IE, replace this :

```
var op = 1 - (window.pageYOffset / slider.offsetHeight);
```

by this:

```
var op = 1 - ($(document).scrollTop() / slider.offsetHeight);
```

---

#### Code:

**html:**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="overflow"></div>
```

**css:**

```
#slider{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#overflow{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var ovf, slider;

$(function(){
    ovf = this.getElementById("overflow");
    slider = this.getElementById("slider");
    winResize();
    $(window).bind({resize: winResize, scroll: winScroll});
});

function winResize(){   
    ovf.style.top = slider.offsetHeight + "px";
}

function winScroll(){
    var op = 1 - (window.pageYOffset / slider.offsetHeight);
    slider.style.opacity = op; 
}
```